# Need simple example of file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need a very simple example. I simply want to use `ng-file-upload` to get the file body into an object field defined as a binary array in my view controller. I don't need to upload the file to a file system on a server. The doc for `ng-file-upload` is quite complex. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.save()">                    
    <div class="widget-content user">
       Business Logo: <input type="file" 
    ngf-select ng-model="vm.logoFile" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB"
    required autofocus placeholder="Logo image file" />
   </div>
   <div class="app-command-bar">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"
        ng-disabled="isSaveDisabled()"
        title="SignUp">
    <i class="icon-save"></i> Sign Up
   </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

and in my controller upon submit:

```
     if (vm.logoFile != null) {
            log("logoFile" + vm.logoFile);
            log("logoFile type: " + vm.logoFile.type);
            log("logoFile name: " + vm.logoFile.name);
            vm.logoFile.upload = Upload.http({
                url: "",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': vm.logoFile.type
                },
                data: vm.logoFile,
            });
            log("Attempting upload");
            // we are trying to post the page again; no can do
            vm.logoFile.upload.then(function (response) {
                vm.logoFile.result = response.data;  //supposed to be the file binary at this point
                log("File result: " + vm.logoFile.result);
            });
```

I'm having a concept problem regarding the upload location. I'm using "" in the URL which posts to my page, but I'm getting `405 Method not Allowed`. Seems to me I'm trying to repost this page. I'm trying to just get the binary data from the file; I don't want to upload the file to a server. Any suggestions? Thanks.

ok..upon further thought. I need an entrypoint on my web app to accept the upload requests. My web app so far is a pure javascript SPA. What kind of entrypoint do I need to add to the application? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: I don't have any code as of yet; I was looking at the doco and it is to complex

Comment: At least show the part of the documentation that is confusing you; if you can't get that far, people are unlikely to be able to help you.

Comment: basically the huge <div> with all of the options...it's mind boggling...

Comment: I'll ask some questions: 1. why is the URL needed? The input tag knows where the file is and i'm assuming it can upload it into the directive at minimum. 2. how do I get the file body (I don't need name or type) from the directive into my controller, where I can stuff it in my object field as a binary array and send it to my backend for updating it in my database (as a BLOB).

Comment: you could upload file via ajax($http) using formData, but before u need to have server(backend) code ready.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone another way, but am posting as an answer here for those poor slobs like me that need a simple solution. I just added an Angular service that has this function:

```
     function uploadfile(file) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            defer.resolve(event.target.result);
        };
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

When the file bytes come back I just parse the type and the pure base64string into the fields (using .split(",")) I needed to post to my database on the backend.

Comment: Hi Al Blues, i know it's too old thread, but is the argument you passed into uploadfile the one from ngf-select ng-modal? or you don't use ng-file-upload at all?